# How do I iterate over a container with KendoUI widgets and get their values using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, model-view-controller, kendo-ui

I'm working with jQuery and KendoUI for MVC.  I have a `ul` called `#overview` and each list item has a different kind of KendoUI widget in it.  Those widgets are the like of text boxes, multi select, ranger sliders and dropdown lists.  There is a button that the user can click which runs a jQuery function to gather the content of all these widgets.

The problem I have is that these widgets have Kendo specific code to access their values and text attributes such as `$("MyControl").data("kendoDropDownList).text();`, I am using a `.each` loop to iterate over the `li` and I need a way to grab the data from the varying controls and I was wondering if there was a clean way to do that?

With so many controls available it will make for a complex piece of code to check for every possible control that may be there.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is kinda tricky. There is an obscure method called [`kendo.widgetInstance()`](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/kendo/methods/widgetinstance) that whatever element you pass intto it, it will check for a widget and return it's instance.

```
var $date = $("#date").kendoDatePicker({ value: (new Date()) });
console.log(kendo.widgetInstance($date).value());
```

[Demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/AbURABIy)